# How to sanitize a physical address (in Node... to prevent hacking)?

Tags: security, sanitization

I have a Node app that collects the user's address and sends it to the Yahoo PlaceFinder api (which returns the user's geolocation).

The user should fill out the "address" field and click submit.

Many different address formats are acceptable, such as:

- 90210 (just zip)
- 123 fake street, beverly hills, CA 90210
- 123 fake street, 90210
- ... etc

I'm not concerned if the user enters a valid address or not. I don't even want to think about what RegEx would be needed for that.

I am concerned about security.

What steps (if any) should I take to sanitize the user's input before processing it with with my Node app - http.get()request to YahooPlace finder api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give a fairly pragmatic answer beyond the usual "sanitise your untrusted data against a white list of acceptable values" response. When you say "collects the user's address", are you actually either:

1. Passing it to a location such as a database where you might be worried about injection attacks
2. Rendering it to a page where you might be worried about an XSS attack

If you're simply taking the input and passing it off to Yahoo, then the problem is more theirs than yours as you're not exposing yourself to either of the above attack vectors. You might find that if this is the case, there's not a lot of point in going down the sanitisation path which will inevitably be very difficult against something as variable as a free-form address.

Answer (score 1):

I dare say the simplest method would be to apply a regex to their input, allowing only alphanumeric characters, along with perhaps a comma and a period.  I'm not sure if that would allow all valid addresses through, but if it fails you could display an error message to the effect of "only use [A-z0-9,.]"

That should, in theory, mitigate most types of exploits you would see, as they would most likely need some form of control character to break your code.  Barring an overflow of some sort, I'm pretty sure commas and periods are relatively harmless given your situation.